# Override Standard Marketing Cloud Connect LeadActions / ContactActions (Visualforce Pages)

Tags: visualforce, marketing-cloud, visualforce-component

Standard MC Connect package includes LeadActions and ContactActions (Visualforce Pages)

Currently, on the Lead and Contact Record Page, 3 buttons are shown ugly with a large margin at the bottom.

[image: Lead and Contact Record Page]

Is there any solution to how these buttons can be overridden in Lightning to make them look more beautiful?